# How to lock screen with keyboard on Linux Mint (LXDE)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, lxde

I'm trying out Linux Mint 11 with LXDE. I'm used to being able to lock the screen with a keyboard combination (for example, Win+L on Windows) rather than tracking down a menu or clicking an icon.

Web search returned Ctrl+Alt+L as a default combination to lock the screen, but this did nothing for me.

Is there a way to do this in LXDE?

**Update**:

The link to http://wiki.lxde.org in the answer has the required steps, except that in Mint 11 the file is called `mintlxde-rc.xml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use mint10 where you go to menu-> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.
I have not been able to find any gui lxde and do not have away of testing these methods.
[LXDE:Questions](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Hotkeys#How_do_I_change_the_hotkeys.3F),
Search to Index 3. mouse/keyboard,for mint 11 the file is mintlxde-rc.xml.
[From Stray notes](http://stray-notes.blogspot.com/search?q=shortcuts),
[From Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/obhotkey/index.php?title=Main_Page),
[From openbox/org](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Modifiers),
I hope something helps.

Comment: Thanks @mic84. The steps in your first link (wiki.lxde.org) worked. The file was named slightly differently for me, so I'll update the question with the exact steps.

Answer (score 8):

In Linux Mint 18.3 (*Sylvia*) GUI, go to `Menu` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`.

Expand the `System` tab and you should see a `Lock Screen` shortcut setting.

The default shortcut to lock the screen is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to the `<keyboard>` section of ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml :

```
keybind key="C-A-l">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Then run this command:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Now Ctrl-Alt-l should lock the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm being lazy and just type **xlock** in a terminal, which I always have opened even if it's a GUI session. It works everywhere and is not tied to a particular hotkey combination that may be unavailable somewhere.

Comment: vtest: Thanks for the tip. I must be lazier than you though...I'm trying to avoid all those characters in 'xlock'... ;)

Comment: @Ash: you can always have some unique alias to make it shorter. For example, use **ss** as alias for calling your favorite screen locker (I recently learned about slock thanks to this question and will certainly try it).